# How to send notifications to specific logged users using primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'd like to send notifications to specific logged users. I am using primeface 4 community.

How do I do that? Should I consume the messages using a polling component and checking if the logged user is the same as the message receiver? Or is there any other smarter way to do that?

Don't need to provide code. Just high level instructions are ok.

Comment: You could do it with `push`. Just let the desired users subscribe. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml

Comment: Thanks. Push seems to be the right way to go. I'm gonna try to change the "chat" demo approach a little and see if I can make it work. Some extra work may be needed, since I am working in a clustered environment.